# How to package the wearable apps?

Tags: android, wear-os

Hy I am trying to package the wearable app using Android studio 1.0.1 and I am following the steps given on this link https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html and I followed the steps over 3 successfully .  but when go for 4th step , that is to click the Build menu on AS and to click the signed apk , but after that I got a selection box , weather to sign the mobile  apk  or to sign the wear app.

Now this is a point which is confusing for me , Should I go for Mobile app and It is all done and I would be able then to install the app on mobile and it will push the wear app to wearable or should I first signed the wear app and then paste this signed app in the mobile app and then select the sign mobile app , ??? what should I do to make it work

I think that my question is quite clear now. waiting for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should build and sign your just mobile application. Wearable aplication will be signed automatically and introduced inside mobile .apk

You could check this opening the .Apk generated as a .zip. Wear apk will be in res/raw/ folder.

Comment: there is no wear apk in assets folder

Comment: Yep you are right, my fault. the wear .apk is in res/raw/

Comment: now I checked there are two files on is for android_wear_micro_apk.apk and other one is gtm_analytics

Comment: I think so. gtm_analytics is a library you have imported. And android_wear_micro_apk is the .APK of your wear app. It should be installed in your watch automatically when you install the mobile app in your phone

Comment: It's signed and added to the mobile apk *only* if you add the dependency as greywolf82 stated in his reply below. I'd rather validate his answer, being more complete.

Comment: Yes you can , but I cant As I have no permission under the rules

Comment: @jDur thanks for replying. You cleared me every thing

Answer (score 2):

You have to simply create a module of your wear app with the same applicationId. In addition you add to your gradle script file of your mobile app:

```
dependencies {
   //something bla bla
   wearApp project(':mywearable')
}
```

Generete from Android Studio menu your release APK for your mobile app. You'll see actually that two apk are generated, the mobile and the wear apk but it's only a convenience for you. If you check the mobile apk you'll see the wear app inside, so don't worry use always to publish the mobile apk.